# Accessing argc in main function of C program

Tags: c, argc

I am currently trying to check the number of arguments supplied in the command line before my program executes. However, when I write `argc` within the main function, `argc` is underlined in red. When I hover over `argc`, I see a message saying, "`Symbol argc could not be resolved`." What could be happening?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("%d", argc);
}
```

I can access argv without any issues. I am using the GCC C Compiler and working in Eclipse in a Unix environment.

EDIT: Renaming argc to something else, restarting Eclipse, and then changing that name back to argc resolved my issue. Thank you to everyone who helped me.

Comment: you need to edit your question, and show your code ( as text).  Does it compile?

Comment: I have edited my question. It does not compile.

Comment: Looks fine to me.  Strange.

Comment: Can't reproduce, it works fine here: https://godbolt.org/z/e1avM5WYK.  This may be a bug or misconfiguration in your IDE.

Comment: Just curious, does anything change if you rename `argc` to something else?  Any chance that one of the `argc` instances actually contains some special character that only looks similar to the ASCII character?  (Did you copy/paste the code in your question from your actual file, or retype it?)

Comment: I will try naming argc to something else.

Comment: Yes. Renaming argc worked.

Comment: From what I see on Google, there seems to be something not quite right with the way Eclipse handles this kind of stuff, leading to similar problems... Restart Eclipse and rename back to “argc” and see if it still works...?

Comment: Restarting Eclipse solved my issue. Thank you.